# how to check if an object is not in the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted this code to send a **"no"** when it doesn't find the object **"Player_1"** but when it finds it, it sends **"yes"** in the debug log but when I remove it simply
don't send **"no"**

```cs
{
    public GameObject _objeto1;
    public GameObject _objeto2;
    public float _distancia1;
    public 

    void Start()
    {
        _distancia1 = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _objeto1 = GameObject.Find("Player_1");
        _distancia1 = Vector3.Distance(_objeto1.transform.position, _objeto2.transform.position);

        if (_objeto1 == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("sim");
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("nao");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With "in the scene", you mean if the object is visible by the camera or it is actually not in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public GameObject _objeto1;
    public GameObject _objeto2;
    public float _distancia1;

    void Start()
    {
        _distancia1 = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _objeto1 = GameObject.Find("Player_1");
        if (_object1 != null)
        {        
            _distancia1 = Vector3.Distance(_objeto1.transform.position,  _objeto2.transform.position);
        }

        if (_objeto1 != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("sim");
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("nao");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for question!

GameObject.Find() returns GameObject if it's exist on scene and returns "null" when there is no object. So you can use if statment to check if _objeto1 is null.

```
_objeto1 = GameObject.Find("Player_1");
if (_objeto1 == null)
{
    Debug.Log("nao");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Yes");
}
```

And don't use '_' for public fields. It's bad practice. You can use it for private fields.